# Create a Jira Issue from Google form using APP Script

Tags: google-apps-script, jira, google-forms

I am trying to create a Jira issue when a Google Form is filled and sends the email notification to corresponding recipients.

I was successful in creating a Google Form, then an Apps script trigger, and finally the Jira issue was created using Rest API and notifying the recipients using email.

Now, I am looking to update the assignee and reporter names accordingly in the Jira issue using the data from Google form. Reporter name will be the person that filled the Form (available in the underlying Gsheet).
For the assignee, I have data populated in the same sheet using a Vlookup.

[image]

Can we update the Assignee and Reporter fields in this way?
If yes, could anyone please help me to suggest a solution or workaround?

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Can you share the code